# How to count different stages in R from one stage to another stage

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to R and would like to get the desired output

My df is like this and want to count of stage 3 to stage 4 , stage 3 to stage 5 and stage 3 to stage 6,
I am only interested in from S3 to different Stages 4,5,6 and if begin stage is S1 or something else I don't need that also if it is from S3  to S3 for a particular week we don't need

[image]

and want to get desired results

[image]

Comment: please share input data using `dput(head(your_input_dataframe))`

Comment: Please follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page when posting. In particular, provide reproducible input -- not images.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck  I will do from next time, I am new to this  sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidy option:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(42)
dat <- tibble(
  week = as.Date("2018-01-01") + cumsum(sample(c(0L, 7L), size = 10, replace = TRUE)),
  begins = c(rep("S3", 9), "S1"),
  ends = sample(c("S4", "S5", "S6"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
dat
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    week       begins ends  stringsAsFactors
#    <date>     <chr>  <chr> <lgl>           
#  1 2018-01-08 S3     S5    FALSE           
#  2 2018-01-15 S3     S6    FALSE           
#  3 2018-01-15 S3     S6    FALSE           
#  4 2018-01-22 S3     S4    FALSE           
#  5 2018-01-29 S3     S5    FALSE           
#  6 2018-02-05 S3     S6    FALSE           
#  7 2018-02-12 S3     S6    FALSE           
#  8 2018-02-12 S3     S4    FALSE           
#  9 2018-02-19 S3     S5    FALSE           
# 10 2018-02-26 S1     S5    FALSE           

dat %>%
  filter(begins == "S3") %>%
  group_by(week, ends) %>%
  tally() %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "ends", values_from = "n", values_fill = list(n = 0))
# # A tibble: 7 x 4
# # Groups:   week [7]
#   week          S5    S6    S4
#   <date>     <int> <int> <int>
# 1 2018-01-08     1     0     0
# 2 2018-01-15     0     2     0
# 3 2018-01-22     0     0     1
# 4 2018-01-29     1     0     0
# 5 2018-02-05     0     1     0
# 6 2018-02-12     0     1     1
# 7 2018-02-19     1     0     0
```

Comment: thanks for that pivot is better solution, I was going through filter many conditions and get to answers, this is more concise